# Como exibir 2 colunas de 2 tabelas diferentes no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 2 tabelas com várias colunas.

Gostaria que exibisse colunas individuais de mais de uma tabela ao mesmo tempo:

```
tabela1 | tabela2

Nome    | Apelido
```

Comment: Consegue fornecer mais detalhes?

Comment: As duas tabelas são concactenadas uma a outra? Tem algum campo em comum?

Comment: Isso é algo bem simples. Tem algum requisito especial? Como elas estão relacionadas? Aguardo informações adicionais para melhorar a resposta

Comment: Deu certo aqui com os comandos que os colegas responderam, era só isso mesmo :SELECT tabela1.nome, tabela2.apelido from tabela1, tabela2 conforme o Bigown respondeu. Estou aprendendo agora a usar os comandos do mysql. Obrigado pelas ajudas.. Assim que pitar mais dúvidas irei chama-los.

Comment: @David eu vi que você tentou aceitar outras respostas também. Aceitação só pode uma. Mas logo você poderá votar em todas as respostas, ou perguntas que quiser, mesmo em perguntas que não sejam suas. Os votos ajudam classificar o conteúdo correto quando você puder avaliar. A aceitação mostra qual resposta você achou que responde melhor o que você queria. Veja o [tour]. Bem-vindo ao site, acho que vai gostar aqui.

Comment: é tentei mesmo, rs obrigado. Meio perdido ainda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
SELECT tabela1.nome, tabela2.apelido FROM tabela1, tabela2;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/TwoTables.sql).

Após o `SELECT` você vai colocar a lista de colunas que deseja que seja mostrada. Quando tem mais de uma tabela é importante qualificar a coluna por completo, ou seja, dizer a que tabela a coluna pertence, em outras palavras, dar um sobrenome para ela, assim fica mais óbvio de onde vem essa coluna e evita ambiguidade se as tabelas possuírem colunas com mesmo nome. Em alguns casos o nome da tabela pode ser omitido mas costuma ser interessante colocar assim mesmo.

Depois a cláusula `FROM` você lista todas as tabelas que devem estar disponíveis na consulta. Sem isso você não poderá usá-las para todas as operações. É possível criar um apelido para o nome da tabela como demonstrado em outra resposta mas não vem ao caso para o que você quer. É só uma facilidade quando vai usar muitas vezes o nome da tabela.

Answer (score 2):

Presumindo que vc tem uma tabela1 com os seguintes campos:

```
Tabela1
-Id - Integer
-Nomes - String
-IdTabela2 - Integer
```

e uma Tabela2 com os seguintes campos:

```
Tabela2
-Id - Integer
-Apelidio - String
```

executamos a seguinte query:

```
SELECT t1.Nome, t2.Apelido
FROM Tabela1 AS t1, Tabela2 AS t2
WHERE t1.IdTabela2 == t2.id
```

na terceira linha `WHERE t1.IdTabela2 == t2.id` diz que "onde a coluna IdTabela2  da Tabela1 seja igual a coluna ID da tabela2", ocorrendo assim o relacionamento entre as duas tabelas, ou seja, a *query* irá apresentar todos os nomes com seus respectivos apelidos que estão relacionados através da *foreign key* `IdTabela2`, espero que tenha dado para entender.

Comment: Seria interessante explicar sua resposta, assim além de saber como fazer ele vai entender o porque

Comment: Editei, ficou melhor Erlon Charles?

Comment: Agora ficou bem melhor, quanto mais completas as respostas mais elas irão ajudar em futuras buscas por estar perguntas. Bem vindo :D

Answer (score 1):

Simples assim:

```
SELECT
  `tabela1`.`Nome`,
  `tabela2`.`Apelido`
FROM
  `tabela1`,
  `tabela2`;
```

Answer (score -1):

E quando se tem um select usando inner join e se quer percorrer várias tabelas para exibir. Exemplo:

id - razaosocial - comum - opme
                   58     89

Nesse exemplo "Comum" é um select percorrendo X tabelas e "Opme" é outro select percorrendo X tabelas, Ambos passam pela tabelas que tem o campo de razaosocial. Com tal exemplo eu não sei como estruturar para mostrar a informações. Já tentei usar subselect e union all, mas não deu certo. Com union all eu consigo mostrar as informações mas elas ficam no campo de comum e não é isso que pretendo quero exibir coluna ao lado de coluna.